# Error : Getting this exception while trying to select from list dropdown in selenium "option element is not in a select"

Tags: list, selenium, xpath, dropdown

I have been trying to select an element from list dropdown(not select dropdown). Everytime I try this, selenium is able to locate the element using xpath but it does not click on the element. Instead it throws an exception that says :

`org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: option element is not in a select`

HTML :

```
<list id="cmds" class="dropdown-menu">

    <option value="{YEAR}">{YEAR}</option>
    <option value="{DAY}">{DAY}</option>
    <option value="{HOME}">{HOME}</option>

</list>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML from the page and your current code attempt(s).

Comment: @JeffC  Thank you for reminding. Is this good? :)

Comment: You forgot to include your current code but I see the problem already and it's just as was stated in the error message. The OPTION tags are not inside a SELECT tag. If you've copied the HTML correctly, the site appears to have malformed HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the Action library available from selenium.

```
            import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

            WebElement newitem= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[text()=\"{YEAR}\"]"));
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.build();
            action.moveToElement(newitem).click();
            action.perform();
```

This hovers over to the element found by xpath and clicks on it.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to click on the drop down.
And then use the below xpath which returns a list of WebElements(drop down values) and using for loop you can click on any dropdown value.

```
//list[@id='cmds']/option
```

Sample code in Java:

```
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter xpath for the dropdown"));
dropDown.click();
List<WebElement> valuesInDropDown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//list[@id='cmds']/option"));
for (WebElement value : valuesInDropDown) {
    if (value.getText().equals("{YEAR}"))
        value.click();
}
```

Comment: This is perfect.. For me, I did not want to use the for loop. That was why I was looking for other options :)